# Android studio app

Tags: java, android, parsing, import

I'm trying to retrieve from Parse 2 Strings and one image trying to make a list. But I'm doing somthing wrong because this is my result:

[image]

As you can see I neither know how to see all the content of each row. This are my code:

CustomCanguros.java

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import java.io.File;

@ParseClassName("Canguros")

public class CustomCanguros extends ParseObject {

public String getName(){
    return getString("Nombre");
}
public void setName(String name){
    put("Nombre", name);
}

public String getTipo(){
    return getString("Tipo");
}
public void setTipo(String tipo){
    put("Tipo", tipo);
}
public ParseFile getFoto(){
    return getParseFile("icon");
}
public void setFoto(ParseFile foto){
    put("icon",foto);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
return getParseFile("icon")+"\n"+           
getString("Nombre")+"\n"+getString("Tipo");

}

}

ReservaCanguro.java:

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReservaCanguro extends ListActivity{
List<CustomCanguros> canguros= new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reserva_canguro);

    ParseQuery<CustomCanguros> query = new ParseQuery<CustomCanguros>     
    ("Canguros");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<CustomCanguros>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<CustomCanguros> list, ParseException e) {
            if ( e != null ){
       Toast.makeText(ReservaCanguro.this,"Error "+ 
       e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            for( CustomCanguros canguro : list){
                CustomCanguros newcanguro = new CustomCanguros();
                newcanguro.setName(canguro.getName());
                newcanguro.setTipo(canguro.getTipo());
                canguros.add(newcanguro);

            }
            ArrayAdapter<CustomCanguros> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
   (ReservaCanguro.this,
   android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,canguros);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
   }


   }


reserva_canguro.xml

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I'm starting developing apps since 2 months, sorry for my lack of knowledge :S

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing the results of the query, you're setting the values for Name and Tipo, but not Foto (you're not invoking `setFoto` in `newCanguro` inside the loop).

Additionally, I would suggest looking at [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)